# Install OpenLiteSpeed on DirectAdmin

Tags: apache, directadmin, litespeed

Currently i have `DirectAdmin` installed on Apache.
I want to install `OpenLiteSpeed` with `CustomBuild 2.0` by `DirectAdmin`.

```
./build update
./build set webserver openlitespeed
./build set mod_ruid2 no
./build set php1_mode lsphp
./build openlitespeed
./build php n
./build rewrite_confs
```

If i install it, my apache will stopped automatically?
and all files httpd in `DirectAdmin` in `File Editor` was deleted or useless?
If I unistall `Apache`, `DirectAdmin` will was crash?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

If you install Openlitespeed, Apache will be stopped and removed automatically. All configurations are also directly converted and no other step is needed other than what you mentioned in your post. Do not try to uninstall Apache directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely run these commands, but there are a few important points:

- After converting apache to openlitespeed it will no longer be possible to return to Apache safely.
- You cannot change any settings using WebAdmin in DirectAdmin. The settings need to be made manually via the configuration file in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

When you access WebAdmin from Openlitespeed with **DirectAdmin** you will notice that it is not possible to change any settings there. (read-only). To modify the OLS settings you need to modify the files that are informed in the link
https://openlitespeed.org/kb/directadmin-configuration-files/

Comment: Please merge this with your other answer